# C++ Builder & ADO - how to show correct values after trigger execution?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, triggers, c++builder, ado

I created a simple test application that uses ADO components (TADOTable) and TDBGrid for inserting and updating table records. SQL Server database table that I use has INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE trigger that capitalizes first character of a column 'Name'.

The problem is that TDBGrid is not aware of the changes made by the trigger, and only after reopening the table I see the correct value. If I set the column 'Name' value to 'test' the value stored in database table is correct - 'Test', but TDBGrid displays incorrect value - 'test'.

How can I force TDBGrid and other TDB components to automatically show correct value after trigger is executed?

Comment: You need to re-fetch the updated (inserted) record as it was modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADO has [Dynamic Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/ado-dynamic-properties) you can use for this purpose.
You can set `Update Resync` property to `adResyncAutoIncrement or adResyncUpdates or adResyncInserts`:

```
uses ..., ADOInt;

ADODataSet1.Properties['Update Resync'].Value := 
  adResyncAutoIncrement or adResyncUpdates or adResyncInserts;
```

right after you Open the dataset, and ADO will re-sync the inserted/updated *records*. You must also have a PK `IDENTITY` column.

You can also use:

```
ADODataSet1.Properties['Update Criteria'].Value := adCriteriaKey;
```

So that ADO uses only the PK for updates.

Personally, I would not have used a trigger for this, and would used `OnBeforePost` to capitalize the text.

BTW, I strongly recommend not to get into the habit of using `TADOTable` which will always use `SELECT * FROM` internally.. use a `TADODataSet` instead.

Comment: I just finished testing, and yes - Update Resync is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I was curios to know because I didn't actually test it with your specific details (which I had to guess).

Comment: It's all OK. I'm just curious, are there any unwanted side-effect of this solution and why is it not a default behaviour?

Comment: The only "side effect" is an *extra* `SELECT` statement sent to the DB by the ADO provider to fetch the inserted/updated record. the default is `adResyncAutoIncrement` only.

Comment: Great! Thanks again for this solution. Been searching for it for a long time :)